# Material-ui Data Grid columns rendering

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Does anyone know how to get dropdown fields in `DatGrid` showing properly? Setting the `TextField` height doesn't work as expected for me.
Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-leftpad-eixec?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the value of property `box-sizing` to `inital`:

```
.MuiSelect-select.MuiSelect-select {
  box-sizing: initial;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-microservice-ner57?file=/src/styles.css:0-120

Answer (score 0):

Just add an inputProps like this to your textfield:

```html
      <TextField
        select
        SelectProps={{
          native: true
        }}
        inputProps={{
          style:{height: '100%'}
        }}
        size="small"
      >
        <option>Sel1</option>
        <option>Sel2</option>
      </TextField>
```